# How to deploy Angular 2 Application on IIS

Tags: angular, deployment

I am trying to deploy my Angular 2 Application on my local IIS. When I am running my application in my local machine, it is running well with no errors but when I hosted it in my local IIS it throws 404 error for some files inside node_modules. please be informed that the node_modules folder is not hosted on IIS. I am getting the following errors.

[image: Please see this image]

It clearly seems that it is not able find those files as it can't detect the node_modules folder but my question is do we need that huge sized node_modules to be hosted ? If not then what is the way to get the polyfills --

```
<script src="../../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../../systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Please suggest a way to deploy the application on IIS.

Comment: Have you tried building/compiling the app to HTML and JS, then deploying it statically?

Comment: Thats what I am doing currently. I simply published my project folder to a location on pointed to that in my local IIS and it throws that errors.

Comment: Because you're referencing scripts and stylesheets from Node modules, rather than including them in your build. Please provide more information about your setup.

Comment: Are you using webpack/angular-cli/something else? why are you importing your node_modules directly into your html?

Comment: @yadejo - I am using the SystemJS approach given in Angular.io documention. There they have importing the browser polyfills in html from node_modules. is there any other way ?

Comment: If you want to host your app on IIS, I recommend looking into webpack.

Comment: @AmitAnand were you able to make it work in IIS?  Do you mind sharing your findings?